# sum of all positive numbers of lower diagonal in 2d array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

So there is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double M[50][50];
    int eilst;
    int sum=0;
    cout <<"row and colum number:";
    cin >> eilst;
    cout << "matrix elemkents:";
    for (int i=0; i<eilst ; i++)
        for (int j=0 ; j<eilst ; j++)
    cin>> M[i][j];
    cout<<endl;
    cout<< "sum: \n";
    for (int i =0 ; i<eilst ; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0 ; j<eilst ; j++)
        if ( i > j )
        {
            if (M[i][j]>0){
                sum= sum + M[i][j];
        cout<< sum<<"";
        }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Its is printing all my code lower diagnol matrix, but now I added sum method, because I want to add all my positive elements in that array. Maybe you could tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow My sum isn't correct. It gives me very huge numbers. for example 4+4 = 810

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;   
int main() {

double M[50][50];
int eilst;
int sum=0;
cout <<"row and colum number:";
cin >> eilst;
cout << "matrix elemkents:";
for (int i=0; i<eilst ; i++)
{
    for (int j=0 ; j<eilst ; j++)
{
cin>> M[i][j];
cout<<endl;
}
}
cout<< "sum: \n";
for (int i =0 ; i<eilst ; i++)
{
    for (int j=0 ; j<eilst ; j++)
{
    if ( i > j )
    {
        if (M[i][j]>0)
            sum= sum + M[i][j];
    }
    }
}
 cout<< sum<<"";
  cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I think this will work

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you, you can mention it as helpful :-)